# React Native and telenet commands

Tags: node.js, react-native, telnet

I am wanting to send telnet commands to a local switcher that is setup through a lan connection to the router. I was wondering if I can send these commands using React Native TCP and if not what would be the best way to do so and how should I set out the architecture for the application.

Please and Thank you.

I have contacted the creator of the react-native-telnet-client npm package and he said he doesn't recommend using it but using direct commands in the frontend framework, but I am unsure how to do this exactly.